# Chrome reports ERR_INVALID_HANDLE for intranet sites

Tags: google-chrome, browser

In Chrome (51.0.2704.84 m) and Chrome Canary (53.0.2768.0) some intranet pages are failing with ERR_INVALID_HANDLE. Some that do partially load give the same error for resource files (e.g. stylesheets). The same sites on the same PC work fine in Edge and IE 11 (OS is Windows 10). The internet works fine (so it doesn't seem to be a proxy/firewall issue) and these sites were working with Chrome up until a few hours ago. I work in the software development department so know the websites haven't changed and they work for other people using the same version of browser and OS, so it's something specific to this machine.

How do I identify and fix this problem? A web search indicates that the last time Chrome had this problem it was to do with NTLM authentication, but what's puzzling me is that nothings's apparently changed.

Comment: Same issue! I've deleted all saved credentials for the sites, but it still fails. Only in Chrome. have you found a solution?

Comment: I was getting this error on MacOS and it was caused by a 3rd-party firewall app blocking network access